# Show a progress bar during a new screen navigation in Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, progress-bar

In stackoverflow I can find many examples on how to show progress bar inside the screen while running a process in the screen but I don't find an example on showing one between screens.

I have some screens that takes maybe a minute to show when is called. I wish to give the users some feedback while they wait for the new screen to fully show.